# SQL Server query fails on some weird ascii characters

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I have a function that pulls emails from my mailbox and saves them in my DB. Everything works correctly for 95% of queries but for some it fails with the error:

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): message: Unclosed quotation
>   mark after the character string '

I was able to track the characters that were causing the problem. It looks like one of them is ASCII 160 and ASCII 147. When I run a simple `str_replace` on the email I'm able to save the text correctly with no errors. Why it causes the problem?

```
    $body = $this->get_part($imap, $b, "TEXT/HTML");
    if($body == "")
    {
        $body = $this->get_part($imap, $b, "TEXT/PLAIN");
    }
    $header = imap_headerinfo($imap, $b);
    $subject = $header->subject;
    $fromaddress = $header->fromaddress;
    /////////////////////////////
    $data = array('content'=>$body);
    $query = $PDO->prepare('insert into [tbl_test] (content) values (:content)');
    $query->execute($data);
    break;
```

Comment: The first thing that leaps to my mind is an encoding mismatch.

Comment: Seems like a character set issue indeed. Make sure your php input, connection and database are set to the same.
http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/extended-ascii-code/letter-o-circumflex-accent-o-circumflex-ascii-code-147.html

Comment: uth8_encode() before saving the query helped. Thank you very much.

Comment: @user1029829: You should probably add it as answer to this question so it may help others who stumble upon this post later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uth8_encode() before saving the query solved the issue.